# how to clear input field form in array input form fields

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a input field in my form, that is generated in a map like this:

Every 'Valor' is from this map. That are diferent questions with a primary value, and an array of sinoms.

```
{itemsList.map((item, i) => (                  
              <>                
                <div className="row align-items-center"  key={i}>    
                  <div className="row mt-3">
                    <div className="col-md-2">
                      <label htmlFor="link_title" className="form- 
            label text-center mt-1" >
                        <h5> {i + 1}- Valor de la Lista: </h5>
                      </label>
                    </div>         
                    <div className='col-md-4'>                        
                      <input
                        className='form-control'
                        onChange={handleChange}
                        id={i}
                        name='title_item'
                        value={'' || item.title_item}
                        type="text"
                        required
                        onKeyDown={(e) => { e.key === 'Enter' && 
              e.preventDefault(); }}    
                      />                    
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-md-1">
                      <label htmlFor="link_title" className="form- 
             label text-center mt-1" >
                        <h5> Valor: </h5>
                      </label>
                    </div> 
                    <div className='col-md-4'>
                      <input
                        className='form-control'
                        onChange={handleChange}
                        id={i}
                        name='value'
                        value={'' || item.value}
                        type="text"
                        required
                        onKeyDown={(e) => { e.key === 'Enter' && 
              e.preventDefault(); }}    
                      />   
                      
                    </div> 
                  </div>
                </div>
                  <div className='col-md-1 '>
                    <label htmlFor="link_title" className="form-label 
               mt-1" >
                      <h5> Sinonimos: </h5>
                    </label>
                  </div>
                
                      <ul className='col-md-5 ms-auto '>
                      {sinoms.map((sinom, i) => (
                         item.sinonimos.includes(sinom)  ?
                        <>                            
                          <li key={i}>
                            <div>
                              {sinom}{''}                                 
                              <i className="bi bi-x-circle ms-3" 
                       style={{color: 'red'}} type='button'  
                                onClick={() => {                                    
                                  deleteSinom(sinom);
                                }}>
                              </i>                                 
                            </div>
                          </li> 
                        </>                             
                      : null
                      ))
                      } 
                      <input className="col-md-3 me-2 mt-3"                                
                            key={item.idResponse}
                            value={nuevosin}
                            //name={nuevosin} //works but not clean when click button
                            id={item.idResponse}
                            onChange={e => 
             (setNuevosin(e.target.value.trimRight(), 
               e.target.name))}
                            onKeyDown={(e) => { e.key === 'Enter' && 
                   e.preventDefault(); }}    
                          />
                          <button className="btn btn-outline-primary 
                        col-md-4 " type='button' onClick={() => ( 
                     handleClick(item.idResponse))}>
                            Inserta un Nuevo Sinonimo
                          </button>
                  </ul>
              </>
            ))}
```

This is a image where you are in the edit screen.
[image]

if i use value={nuevosin} when i try to input data in a field all the fields show the same value. if i use name={nuevosin}, works, but then, when i click the button to insert the value, the field not cleared.

I would like, that, when i fill a field, just fill that one and when i click the botton to add the sinom, clear the field.

I don't know how to solve this.

Some can help me to clear my mind? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are using a single state to manage all of your inputs. Please make sure to understand react and state management basics before writing the code. Although your request is highly unusual and its not the best idea to not know how many inputs you are having beforehand, I have managed to get your code working.

```js
const {
  useState
} = React;
const App = () => {
  const itemsList = [{
    idResponse: 1
  }, {
    idResponse: 2
  }, {
    idResponse: 3
  }];
  const [nuevosin, setNuevosin] = useState({});
  console.log(nuevosin);

  return ( <
    React.Fragment > {
      itemsList.map((item, i) => ( <
        React.Fragment key = {
          item.idResponse
        } > < input className = "col-md-3 me-2 mt-3"
        value = {
          nuevosin[[item.idResponse]]
        }
        id = {
          item.idResponse
        }
        onChange = {
          e => setNuevosin(prevValue => ({ ...prevValue,
            [item.idResponse]: e.target.value
          }))
        }
        onKeyDown = {
          (e) => {
            e.key === 'Enter' && e.preventDefault();
          }
        }
        /> <
        button className = "btn btn-outline-primary col-md-4 "
        type = 'button'
        onClick = {
          () => (handleClick(item.idResponse))
        } >
        Inserta un Nuevo Sinonimo <
        /button></React.Fragment >
      ))
    } < /React.Fragment>
  );
}
ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.getElementById("root")
).render( <
  App / >
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Few changes I have made include adding react fragments since react components must only have one parent component. Also adding the key prop to the parent component which is the Fragment now.

Comment: I see your response, and maybe i should add all the code. Because your response, is correct but is not for my case. I can not make a object with the sinoms, because every sinom is for a different object inside other array. But the map() create the input field for every response to handle the sinoms.

Comment: Your query isn't clear. please make sure to formulate your questions clearly. Also include code snippets and expected output if possible. You can edit your above question if necessary.